# How to use getElementById in PHP

Tags: php, css, getelementbyid

I'm trying to select all of the images of a dynamically produced page (drupal6) that have a specific ID, so I can apply a class.

I've read the docs on php.net for getElementById and setIdAttribute but the docs don't make much sense to me, and my attempts at declaring the ID then calling it don't work. I've also looked through the various similar posts here and have not fared better.

I'm really just looking for a base example of how I'm supposed to use these two functions together to get images of a specific ID.

EDIT - 
I'm sorry I was vague - I can't use Jquery/javascript (it was my first choice). based on what I'm doing I can't risk a FOUC. is jquery/javascript going to be my only choice? - I would prefer PHP if possible

Thanks
Stephanie

Comment: An ID must appear only ONCE on a page, so saying "images[PLURAL] with a particular ID" is a non-sequitur.

Comment: PHP is server-side but getElementById is a function in client-side Javascript. I think you have a core confusion here in where the role of PHP is in regards to manipulating CSS after its been rendered and sent to the client.

Comment: @Cody - [Really?](http://es.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

Comment: Hi Marc B, Ok I understand that may be one of my issues (id conflict), then how can i look for getElementByClass? I would eventually be trying to append another class

Answer (score 2):

Here you are some quick and dirty code to take as starting point:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<p><img src="1.jpg"></p><p><img id="foo" src="2.jpg"></p><p><img src="3.jpg"></p>');

$foo = $dom->getElementById('foo');
if( !is_null($foo) && $foo->nodeName=='img' ){
    $foo->setAttribute('class', 'bar');
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'd seen this sample elsewhere - my problem is that I can't load HTML the way this sample suggests. I need the script to be smart enough to look for id="something"

Comment: It'd probably help to know why exactly you are not allowed to load HTML this way (as well as what ways you are allowed to use).

Comment: Hi Álvaro G. Vicario, I'm using drupal6 as my base framework, and the page that contains the images is being created using views. so teh images are coming directly from my DB and if i had to declare the images I'd have to touch my template every time I wanted to add/remove a file with the sample above (I think). thank you for your attention

Comment: I know nothing about Drupal but... If you have neither HTML nor a way to fetch it, what exactly do you want to do with `getElementById()`?

Comment: at the end of the day - I need to dynamically find the images on the page that have a certain class or id, discover their dimentions then based on the image being vertical, horizontal or square apply a (second) class to give it a correct style.

Comment: @Stephanie - Is it me or you are failing the Turing test?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's my computer that can't think, or my failing to use/display function properly - which i'm still kinda hoping to get help on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use javaScript for that. Using jQuery is pretty straightfoward

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $.ready(function(){
    $(".class_name").css("THE CSS YOU WANT TO APPLY TO THE ELEMENTS WITH THE CLASS 'class_name' ");
  });
</script>
```

if you want to catch a specific image, you can use:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $.ready(function(){
    var src_of_img = $("#ID_OF_IMAGE").attr("src");
    alert("the src of the image with the ID you specified is: " + src_of_img);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why 'should' you use JavaScript? Better to do this server side if you got the possibility. And if you use Javascript, do just add a class and apply the styling for that class in your style sheet.

Comment: I'm sorry I was vague - I can't use Jquery/javascript (it was my first choice). based on what I'm doing I can't risk a FOUC. is that going to be my only choice? - i'll add this to my original question

Comment: GolezTrol, you can add the CSS by using the jQuery function .css() just as I said. You just have to put it in the format jQuery uses, ("attr1": "value you want for the attr1") Please read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: I know how it works. It's just bad practice to put the actual markup in your Javascript. People use CSS to separate style from structure, but now you're putting the style into the logic, which is just as bad (or worse). Just specify a class in Javascript and add the markup in the style sheet. Also, don't do in Javascript what should have been done by the server side code.

Comment: HI All,thanks for the help but I wasn't able to get this figured out in time with php. I ended up using jQuery instead. Thank you again for all the help I appreciate it